# Force a java script to fit within an element

Tags: javascript, width

I'm not a programmer, but I need to find out if there's a way to force a java script to fit completely within an element in my page, without showing a horizontal scroll bar.  Sorry if I use the wrong terminology.

Below is a given code that I get from a third party, which I place on my page, to get a display gallery of items.  The problem is that it too wide.

Is there a code I can add, to force the script to completely fit inside the screen (600px wide), so the horizontal scroll bar disappears automatically?

Below is the script:

```
'<noscript>
<p>powered by <a href="https://www.example.com?pid=13903&nid=10&zid=xh20&bid=1301660001">example.com</a></p>
</noscript>
<script id="scriptId_718x940_60872" type="text/javascript" src="//example.com/?scriptId=60872&bid=1301660001&format=718x940&bannerType=3">
</script>
```

I should add that this is a specific html element within my page, and that I'm trying to apply this code only to this element, not to the whole page or the whole site.

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: No JavaScript required as this is best done with CSS.

Comment: I don't see the script, is that just me?

Comment: About edit... That's not a script. That's a tag that links to a script which we cannot see

Comment: I think it's showing now zevee... can you try now?

Comment: I think we need more context @jkuhn. Can you provide the actual link being used by the script tag (I assume `site.com` is a placeholder?) and perhaps a screen shot of the problem?

Answer (score 0):

600 what? I'm going to assume pixels. Add this to your CSS:

```
body {
    max-width: 600px !important;
}
```

Added `!important` in edit

Comment: Yes it's px... I added that, but it didn't work. I stayed displaying the same width. :(

Comment: I tried, but all it did was add it as text at the top of the screen.

Comment: What text did it add?

Comment: If you're seeing `body { max-width: 600px !important; }` on the web page it mean's it is interpreting your css as plain text. If you added zevee's css to the html, try wrapping it in `<style type="text/css">` `</style>` tags.

Comment: (or in a css file)

Comment: Do  you mean like this?: '<style type="text/css"> body {
    max-width: 600px !important;
}</style>   Please remember I'm not a programmer... ☺

Comment: @RockySims Do you mean like this?: '<style type="text/css"> body { max-width: 600px !important; }</style> Please remember I'm not a programmer... ☺

Comment: Yes, exactly like that is what I was thinking.

Comment: It would really help to have a screen shot of the issue. I suspect we're just not understanding your issue clearly enough.

Comment: Thank you everybody... I have to edit to explain my question better, and find out how to add a screenshot. @RockySims

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your html. It isn't very pretty but it should narrow the iframe that is displaying the coupons.

```
<style type="text/css">
    div#ci_gallery {
        width: 600px;
        overflow: scroll;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: thank you for your effort Rocky.  With your script, it kept the same width, but added a vertical scrolling bar to the right.  How did you know it was  a gallery of coupons... smart! ☺

Comment: I googled "scriptId bid format bannerType script" (the query string parameter names from the script tag url + the word script) and found http://www.isheads.com/www/printable-grocery-coupon.com which had an example that looked enough like yours I figured it must be it. Anyway, glad to hear it helped : )

Comment: ok. so nothing seems to work. i'm trying to make it narrower, so the horizontal scrolling bar at the bottom disappears. I really appreciate your effort, though.

Comment: If you're ok with having the part on the right that there isn't room for simply hidden (instead of horizontal scroll) you can change `overflow: scroll;` to `overflow: hidden;`... not sure if that helps.

Comment: No, because people need to be able to scroll the the side, so they can click on the 'next page' option.

Comment: Are we talking about removing the horizontal scroll at the bottom of the page or at the bottom of the coupons iframe within the page?

Comment: If you can manage it, a screenshot of the problem would really help clarify what the issue is and what needs to happen to fix it.

Comment: That's ok.... seems too complicated for me.  Bottom line is that I'm trying to reduce the width, so it fits the screen, making the horizontal scroll disappear automatically.  I think I'm giving up, bc  nothing seems to be working.  Thanks again, I really appreciate your help!